# To which ungulate species does this tooth remainder belong?

Tags: species-identification, mammals, teeth, bone

Found on the beach in Çanakkale, Turkey.

[image]

I have found a lot of these, but this is the first one that has parts like long teeth. My other findings have sometimes 4, sometimes 6 tubes. Very solid, stone-like objects. Is this from a marine animal or is it a non-living formation, I wonder.

Below image is for scale in centimeters.
[image]

View from top and bottom

[image]

[image]

Other similar findings without teeth-like parts

[image]

[image]

Additional images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As I thought from just the side photo in your original post, it looks like a molar of some ungulate. I don't know anything definitive but I'll try to look into it a bit more for you. (you will find other similar photos on our site -- so do a search if you haven't already)

Comment: Thank you. Interesting, I always find these things on the beach. I did not figure out the reason. I'm waiting for your further explanations.

Comment: Whales, dolphins, seals, etc. are marine ungulates. When they die, they are fed upon and what's not edible/eaten/disintegrated sometimes makes it to shore. Your specimens are lovely. The best I ever found was a seal molar. One.

Comment: I have 30 - 40 items like these, but I am still not sure that there is marine remnants in them. I checked seal and dolphin molar after your comment, but they are very different than mine. You are lucky.

Comment: @anongoodnurse right you are about the marine ungulates. However, just [cetaceans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetacea) (e.g., whales and dolphins) are of the Ungulata clade. Seals are order Carnivora and are not considered part of Ungulata. However, all ungulates and the extant members of Carnivora are lumped together in the larger [Ferungulata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferungulata) clade.

Comment: @turin I'm in the throes of final exam season at my university with much grading to do -- I'm unlikely to explore this topic further for the time being. I hope someone else can help you narrow further!

Comment: @theforestecologist no problem. Good luck with your exams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its definitely not a marine mammal, just based on size and general configuration.

those convoluted ever growing teeth are pretty diagnostic of non-cetacean ungulates.

Just based on the pattern I would say bovidae, but that does not narrow it down much in turkey, the H shaped central portion is fairly diagnostic of bovidae. However you have several antelope species not to mention domesticated animals that each would fit that category.

I suggest changing the title to ask for ungulate tooth identification. You need someone specialized in mammalian teeth to narrow it down to species. if you can add more shots of the tooth crown (the complex ends like those below) that is the part most useful for identification. See the examples below. The more you have the better.

[image]

[image]

[Source](http://www.scielo.org.za/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0038-23532019000400021)

Comment: Thank you @John. I will change the title as you suggested and add more tooth crown images.

Comment: I have added new images. Just for your information.

Answer (score -3):

Sheep or goats teeth.

As it was found at the edge of water and may be from drowning, I would predict that it is much more likely to be from a sheep, as goats are so very much safer around water.

[image]
Image from:
"Enamel hypoplasia in molars of sheep and goats, and its relationship to the pattern of tooth crown growth"

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3403278/

But really I know because I was a farmboy.

Comment: A pic from the top is better than one from the side, a side shot is not very diagnostic in mammals.

Comment: I think he's basically right, because: which animal has been cooked in 20,000 BBQ's over the years on beaches in Turkey? sheep an goats. statistically, its 20 times more likely to be a sheep than another common ungulid because of the meshoui type tradition.